# ¿Como solucionar OutOfMemoryError en Android Studio con Glide?

Tags: android-studio, out-of-memory-error, glide

**DESCRIPCIÓN DEL PROBLEMA:**

Estoy cargando 9 imágenes traídas desde mi servidor en 9  ImageViews a través de Glide (entre todas suman 992KB (casi 1 MB)). En celulares *"buenos"* no hay NINGÚN tipo de problema pero en otros celulares peores o con APIS más bajas, la app deja de funcionar y me aparece el error OutOfMemoryError:

(Un ejemplo de dispositivo con el cual obtengo el error es un celular emulado por genymotion, Motorola Moto X 7.0 - API 24 con tamaño 720 x 1280, densidad 320 XHDPI).

**CÓDIGO JAVA CON EL CUAL SE CARGAN LAS 9 IMÁGENES MEDIANTE GLIDE:**

(No muestro la url porque es de mi servidor)

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(url + "img_perros.jpg").diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT).override(300,200).dontAnimate()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.img_loading).error(R.drawable.img_error).into(img_perros);
```

**CÓDIGO XML DE LA ACTIVIDAD EN DONDE SE CARGAN LAS IMÁGENES:**

(Son 9 ImageViews)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_perros"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_animales_domesticos"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_perros"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background_perros"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_perros"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/perros"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_gatos"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/view_separador"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_perros"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_gatos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background_gatos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_gatos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/gatos"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_separador"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_roedores"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/view_separador"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_perros"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_roedores"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background_roedores"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_roedores"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/roedores"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_animales_acuaticos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_roedores"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_animales_acuaticos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background_animales_acuaticos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_animales_acuaticos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/animales_acuaticos"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_aves"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/view_separador"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_animales_acuaticos"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_aves"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background_aves"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_aves"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/aves"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_conejos"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/view_separador"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_animales_acuaticos"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_conejos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background_conejos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_conejos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/conejos"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_tortugas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_conejos"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_tortugas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background_tortugas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_tortugas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/tortugas"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_barra0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="#eceff1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_tortugas"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_otros_animales"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/otros_animales"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#252525"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_barra0"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_ganaderia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_otros_animales"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_ganado"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background_ganaderia"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_ganaderia"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/ganado"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_otros"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_ganaderia"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_otros"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background_otros"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_zoo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/otros"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**ERROR:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: commm.doggy, PID: 1844
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 75000012 byte allocation with 7569840 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:767)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:738)
    at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.getPlaceholderDrawable(GenericRequest.java:416)
    at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.begin(GenericRequest.java:276)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.resumeRequests(RequestTracker.java:83)
    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.resumeRequests(RequestManager.java:180)
    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.onStart(RequestManager.java:203)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.ActivityFragmentLifecycle.onStart(ActivityFragmentLifecycle.java:50)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment.onStart(SupportRequestManagerFragment.java:135)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2730)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:355)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1192)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**EDIT:**

Intenté algo nuevo, usando la clase **BitmapFactory** (esta vez cargo las imágenes desde mi drawable y NO con glide desde el servidor) pero aún así sigo obteniendo el error OutOfMemoryError :(. Ya no se que hacer, tengo la cabeza rota...

**CLASE EN LA QUE IMPLEMENTO BITMAPFACTORY:**

```
public class imagenes_escaladas{

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource (Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){
    // Primera decodificación con inJustDecodeBounds = true para verificar las dimensiones
    final BitmapFactory.Options opciones = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opciones.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId , opciones );
    // Calcula las opciones de inSampleSize .
    opciones.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize ( opciones , reqWidth , reqHeight );
    // Decodifica el mapa de bits con las opciones establecidas de inSampleSize .
    opciones.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource( res , resId , opciones);
}

//PARA CARGAR UNA VERSION REDUCIDA EN MEMORIA
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options opciones , int reqWidth , int reqHeight){
    //Alto y ancho sin procesar de la imagen final
    final int altura = opciones.outHeight ;
    final int anchura = opciones.outWidth ;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if(altura > reqHeight || anchura > reqWidth){
        final int halfHeight = altura / 2 ;
        final int halfWidth = anchura / 2 ;
        //Calcula el valor más grande de inSampleSize que es una potencia de 2 y mantiene tanto alto como ancho que el alto y ancho solicitado.
        while((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth){
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize ;
}

}
```

**CODIGO CON EL QUE CARGO LAS IMAGENES:**

```
img_perros.setImageBitmap(imagenes_escaladas.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.img_perros, 300, 150));
```

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 0):

Me es un poco raro saber que en algunos dispositivos tienes un error de memoria cuando cargas Imágenes en 9 `ImageViews` y estas imágenes en total suman casí 1MB, Glide en realidad optimiza  la imagen.

Te sugiero desactives el uso de caché usando `skipMemoryCache(true)` :

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
.load(url + "img_perros.jpg")
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.override(300,200).dontAnimate()           
.placeholder(R.drawable.img_loading)
.error(R.drawable.img_error)
.into(img_perros);
```

---

Pero debes considerar que en realidad la solución ideal es usar un [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?hl=es-419) que contenga los elementos que muestras en pantalla.

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView/>

            <View/>

            <TextView/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Al usar un `RecyclerView` solo mantendrá en memoria los elementos de la lista que sean visibles, de esta forma se reduce el uso de memoria de manera considerable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias una vez más por tu tiempo @Jorgesys . Hice exactamente lo que me dijiste y aún así obtengo el OutOfMemoryError. Realmente creí que haciendo lo del recyclerview iba a funcionar. Se te ocurre alguna otra cosa?